# what happens if a miner include a transaction already exists in another block?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, mining-theory, block, blockchain-fork

Suppose that I have a Transaction A. (txA)
I send my txA to bitcoin network and full node validate it and put in Mempool and starts to broadcasting it.

A Miner A connect to a fullnode to create a candidate block and wins the POW. In this block there is my txA

A miners B create another block with all different transactions except to my txA.

If block A and block B have the same previous block Hash it's a fork,and if the chain of block A wins, all transaction of block B return to mempool.

But if B Has the previous block hash of A ?
After create a block there is another check of all transactions?
When TxA is in mempool it's unconfirmed when become confirmed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can only exist in one block.  That is why it is safer to wait for 2-6 confirmations before accepting a large transaction.

So to answer the title of your post - a miner can't include a transaction which exists on another block in the same chain since it would not be a valid block.

Comment: thanks, who check these blocks for 2-6 confirmations?

Comment: @monkeyUser: the anxious recipient

Comment: @monkeyUser It's up to the person receiving the Bitcoin to check the number of confirmations.  If you own a Lamborghini dealership an a customer pays with BTC, after 1 confirmation you let the customer drive off.  The chain re-organizes and that BTC is no longer valid, and you don't have the money in your account.  You should have waited for 6 confirmations before letting the customer drive off!